# Method to extract certain Text patterns from a column, between the space and comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, extract

I am trying to find the right way to extract certain patterns from a string and store them in a separate column.

Here is a example:

RAW DATA

```
Smith Pa, Coleman
John Pa-C, Fred
Justin DO, Jack
John OT, Press
Jack ARNP, Nate
Johm DPM, King
```

Desired Output

```
Pa
Pa-C
DO
OT
ARNP
DPM
```

There are titles for providers that i want to store in a seperate column.
Thank you

Comment: What is the pattern here? Do you just want everything after a space before comma?

Comment: So, basically, you want the string between the space and comma? What would be the output of less obvious strings like `Jean Paul J, Knight`, or `J, Br some, thing`?

Comment: Please check the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question with proper sample data, your current attempt and expected results.

Comment: What is the version of sql server ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry not a pattern. I want to extract those particular strings from the column

Comment: @VenkataramanR sql server 2016

Comment: @venky__ yes i want the string before the comma, but not the first name. Just want is between the firstname and lastname.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i am pulling this information from a standardized  healthcare information system. That stores the strings in a consistent pattern. Which is LASTNAME TITLE, FIRSTNAME

Comment: What if the last name itself contains a space (or worst, the title)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled after asking the EHR systems team. According to them, there is no space after the lastname. What i need is the text between the comma and the space, which is the title.

Comment: If there can only be a single space before the comma, Fahmi's answer is a good option.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i get a error with fahimi's answer, which i am trying to fix the error is 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'

Comment: Which means that some of your strings doesn't contain a space before the comma, or doesn't contain commas. Here goes the consistency out the window...

Comment: Oh man. I was told that it follows that same consistency. Let me check with the team again. @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to safely extract the part of the string between the comma and the last space before it using a combination of `stuff`, `charindex`, `reverse`, `len` and `cross apply`.
I write "safely" because a `stuff` based solution will not raise errors if it tries to parse an ill-formatted string, unlike `substring` based solutions that will, as you've seen, throw an "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" error.

First, create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (
    Col varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @T (Col) VALUES
-- Valid examples
('Smith Pa, Coleman'),
('John Pa-C, Fred'),
('Justin DO, Jack'),
('John OT, Press'),
('Jack ARNP, Nate'),
('Johm DPM, King'),
-- Invalid examples
('NoSpaceTITLE, LastName'),
('No Comma TITLE LastName'),
-- Strange, but not really invalid example
('Van Damme ACTOR, Jean-Claude');
```

Note: I've added to the sample data some invalid examples and and also an example that isn't really invalid but is different than other examples.

The query:

```
SELECT    Col
        , NULLIF(STUFF(BeforeComma, 1, LEN(BeforeComma) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(BeforeComma)) + 1, ''), '') As SafeTitle
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(Col, CHARINDEX(',', Col), LEN(Col), '') As BeforeComma) As A
```

Note: using `cross apply` allowed me to calculate the string before the comma once, but use it three times in the query itself.

Results:

```
Col                             SafeTitle
Smith Pa, Coleman               Pa
John Pa-C, Fred                 Pa-C
Justin DO, Jack                 DO
John OT, Press                  OT
Jack ARNP, Nate                 ARNP
Johm DPM, King                  DPM
NoSpaceTITLE, LastName          NULL
No Comma TITLE LastName         NULL
Van Damme ACTOR, Jean-Claude    ACTOR
```

See a live demo on [<kbd>rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/KBHHFQ4999)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below if your actual data is exactly in the same format of your sample-

```
select substring(column1,charindex(' ',column1,1),
charindex(',',column1,1)-charindex(' ','column1,1)) as newcol from tablename
```

Comment: Assuming there can only be one space before the comma, that will work. is that a valid assumption? Only the OP can say.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, and I've mentioned it in the answer very clearly